# How I can define cluster-node in command line spring boot?

Tags: elasticsearch, command-line, spring-boot

I want externalize variables of my spring boot application, all variables is correctly defined by "bash app.war --spring.datasource.url='foo'"

But when I want define elasticsearch variable, I have this error :

> ... 3 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid argument syntax: --spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=
>       at >org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.parse(SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.core.env.SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.>(SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.boot.DefaultApplicationArguments$Source.>(DefaultApplicationArguments.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.boot.DefaultApplicationArguments.>>(DefaultApplicationArguments.java:41)
>       at  org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304)
>       at com.metigate.DatabaseapiApp.main(DatabaseapiApp.java:65)

I have try must syntax but i can't found ..

Thank you for your help

Tibs

Comment: there must be an error in your configuration, without you showing that config, we cannot help

Answer (score 0):

Based on the stacktrace you provided, it looks like you're passing a command line option with an empty value, which is invalid, e.g.

`--spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=`

Can you provide the full command line you're passing to the application?

Reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/env/SimpleCommandLineArgsParser.java#L75

Comment: It's possible that this value was --spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=''
I have finaly use "--spring.config.location=" for specified my configuration file and this work ! 
cf : [Spring boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config)  **cp : 24.3**
Thank you for you answer